# Docker build command failing to run

Tags: docker

I've tried for a long time to work out what my mistake is in the command I am running but just fail to see the problem.

Here is the docker command that runs on the gitlab runner

```
docker build --file docker/myapp.Dockerfile --tag apphouse/myapp --tag apphouse/myapp:8ea7b80 --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.121.130:3128 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.121.130:3128 --build-arg http_proxy=http://192.168.121.130:3128 --build-arg https_proxy=http://192.168.121.130:3128 --build-arg NO_PROXY=10.61.61.5:80,dind:2375,dind:2376,docker:2375,docker:2376,172.20.38.37,172.20.36.45,172.20.36.29,docker.inf.ryui.lk,nexus.inf.ryui.lk,10.61.61.20,10.61.61.3,gitlab.internal1.lk --build-arg no_proxy=10.61.61.5:80,dind:2375,dind:2376,docker:2375,docker:2376,172.20.38.37,172.20.36.45,172.20.36.29,docker.inf.ryui.lk,nexus.inf.ryui.lk,10.61.61.20,10.61.61.3,gitlab.internal1.lk
```

Error

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.
Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

Here's some output to see where the script is running from

Output of 'pwd'

```
/home/gitlab-runner/builds/wV5dDxY4/0/apphouse/myapp
```

Output of 'ls -lrth'

```
total 24K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  820 Mar  4 18:36 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  134 Mar  4 18:36 local-config.yml
drwxrwxr-x 2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   47 Mar  4 18:36 lib
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 8.1K Mar  5 00:12 myapp
drwxrwxr-x 2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   39 Mar  5 12:15 scripts
drwxrwxr-x 3 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   95 Mar  5 12:15 docker
```

Comment: Do you have a directory name at the end after all of those options, usually `.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
docker build --tag apphouse/myapp \
    --tag apphouse/myapp:8ea7b80 \
    --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.121.130:3128 \
    --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.121.130:3128 \
    --build-arg http_proxy=http://192.168.121.130:3128 \
    --build-arg https_proxy=http://192.168.121.130:3128 \
    --build-arg NO_PROXY=10.61.61.5:80,dind:2375,dind:2376,docker:2375,docker:2376,172.20.38.37,172.20.36.45,172.20.36.29,docker.inf.ryui.lk,nexus.inf.ryui.lk,10.61.61.20,10.61.61.3,gitlab.internal1.lk \
    --build-arg no_proxy=10.61.61.5:80,dind:2375,dind:2376,docker:2375,docker:2376,172.20.38.37,172.20.36.45,172.20.36.29,docker.inf.ryui.lk,nexus.inf.ryui.lk,10.61.61.20,10.61.61.3,gitlab.internal1.lk \
    --file docker/myapp.Dockerfile .
```

Comment: Thank you Hussain. I tried 2 things & both fail

1st I tried your answer. It fails with the error - unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/gitlab-runner/builds/wV5dDxY4/0/apphouse/myapp/docker/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: I also tried docker/myapp.Dockerfile
This failed with the error - unable to prepare context: context must be a directory: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/wV5dDxY4/0/apphouse/myapp/docker/myapp.Dockerfile

Comment: can you post content of your dockerfile. You would most probably need to mount required files in docker, so you can access it inside the docker container. See https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Updated the question with dockerfile contents

Comment: Can you rename "myapp.Dockerfile" to "DockerFile" and try again the command I posted in my answer.

Comment: I just did that as you've posted this comment & I see the build is progressing. My goodness... I'll update you on how I go. Thanks a gazillion

Comment: I also updated my answer, so you dont have to rename your docker file and continue to use "myapp.Dockerfile"